# Temporarily unscope model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assume you have two models:

```
class Walrus < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope { where("destroyed_at IS NULL") }
  has_many :bubbles, dependent: :destroy

end

class Bubble < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope { where("destroyed_at IS NULL") }
  belongs_to :walrus

end
```

Now if I destroy a walrus, it will also destroy their bubbles (i.e. set the `destroyed_at` of the `Walrus` and associated `Bubble` models.) If I want to find destroyed `Walrus` records, I can do this:

```
frank = Walrus.create!
frank.bubbles.create!
frank.destroy
# Destroys both the walrus and bubble records
Walrus.unscoped do
  frank = Walrus.first
  # => <Walrus...
  frank.bubbles
  # => []
end
```

What I need is a way to also unscope associations.

The real-world application is a model with lots of associations, returned through an API, so I can't manually go through each one and unscope the association.

Comment: better way is not to use default scope, use named scopes

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ that doesn't solve the problem. Everywhere we currently use the default scope would have to be switched to recursively apply the `where(destroyed_at: nil)` scope. That's the same issue we have here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use **nested `unscoped` blocks**:

```
Walrus.unscoped do
  Bubble.unscoped do
    frank = Walrus.first
    frank.bubbles.to_a
  end      
end
```

Note, when testing this in the Rails 4.2 console, I had to add `.to_a` to the association otherwise the `unscoped` would not be applied for it (this probably has something to do with printing the result - the relation object - in the rails console).